# Deploy war failure on glassfish 4.1

Tags: deployment, hk2, glassfish-4.1

While deploying a war on Glassfish 4.1, I get the following error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jvnet/hk2/internal/ServiceLocatorImpl
at com.timm.mcr.api.guice.APIJerseyModule.configureServlets(APIJerseyModule.java:47)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule.configure(ServletModule.java:55)
at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:62)
at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:340)
at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:110)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:138)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
at com.timm.common.guice.core.guice.AbstractBindingManager.createInjector(AbstractBindingManager.java:68)
at com.timm.common.guice.core.guice.AbstractBindingManager.getInjector(AbstractBindingManager.java:53)
at com.timm.mcr.api.guice.APIGuiceServletContextListener.getInjector(APIGuiceServletContextListener.java:68)
at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceServletContextListener.contextInitialized(GuiceServletContextListener.java:47)
at com.timm.mcr.api.guice.APIGuiceServletContextListener.contextInitialized(APIGuiceServletContextListener.java:38)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:5394)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:743)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5963)
... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1783)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
    ... 51 more
```

Glassfish 4.1 have hk2-locator library installed. Why such error ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your project or something that its using needs that class and probably the containing jar has its scope set to provided.

If you'r using maven try to add hk2-locator-2.1.9.jar to your project:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-locator/2.1.9

or

add the jar to glassfish4/glassfish/domains/yourdomain/lib
and restart the server.

if using maven to check if Your project is using it run:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Comment: Maven dependency tree report "org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.4.0-b10:provided". The jar library is available on <glassfish/modules> directory. Is it normal that the library is not in the application classpath ?

Comment: It is possible that the the versions of hk2-locator inside Your project and on glassfish are different.

If the glassfish version dosnt have the class or the packaging changed it will throw that error.

Comment: For sure, glassfish is installed with the same version oh HK2 libraries. The application classloader does not list glassfish modules libraries. Is it normal? May be a missing configuration?

Comment: I solve the problem by changing the scope attribute in maven POM file on jersey libraries from provided to compile.

Comment: Cool probably the hk2 of jersey was in some way different of the one in glassfish :)